# Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 server not using latest kernel

Tags: server, raspberrypi

On my Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu Server 20.04:

```
root@pi4-4gb:~/initramfs# dpkg -l | grep 'linux-image' | cut -c 1-55
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-1015-raspi   5.4.0-1015.15       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1018-raspi   5.4.0-1018.20       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1019-raspi   5.4.0-1019.21       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1021-raspi   5.4.0-1021.24       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1022-raspi   5.4.0-1022.25       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1023-raspi   5.4.0-1023.26       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1025-raspi   5.4.0-1025.28       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1026-raspi   5.4.0-1026.29       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1028-raspi   5.4.0-1028.31       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1029-raspi   5.4.0-1029.32       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1030-raspi   5.4.0-1030.33       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1032-raspi   5.4.0-1032.35       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1033-raspi   5.4.0-1033.36       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1034-raspi   5.4.0-1034.37       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1035-raspi   5.4.0-1035.38       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1036-raspi   5.4.0-1036.39       
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-1038-raspi   5.4.0-1038.41       
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-1041-raspi   5.4.0-1041.45       
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-1042-raspi   5.4.0-1042.46       
ii  linux-image-raspi              5.4.0.1042.77
```

I regularly run:

`sudo update update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autormeove`

Why is it running kernel `5.4.0-1015.15` instead of `5.4.0.1042.77`?

Comment: Have you made a reboot?

Comment: @nobody Sorry, should have mentioned I regularly reboot the device.

Comment: what gives `sudo update-grub` and `cat /etc/default/grub` ? Please add this to your question.